# OCaml - How do I convert int to string?

Tags: string, int, ocaml

How do I convert an int to a string? Example: 1 to "1".

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use the function `string_of_int` (see the documentation for [Pervasives](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/libref/Pervasives.html), the module containing the functions that are automatically made available in the top level namespace to al OCaml programs).

Answer (score 27):

Another solution is to use the module Printf, which allows you to choose the format of printing:

```
Printf.sprintf "%d" 42
```

gives you "42".

But you might prefer using an octal, hexadecimal, binary, etc representation. For instance,

```
Printf.sprintf "%x" 42
```

gives you "2a" which is the hexadecimal representation of 42.

```
Printf.sprintf "0x%x" 42
```

would give you "0x2a".

See the [Printf documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) for more details.